# Yii2 Rest API basic auth invalid credential

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using postman to test my API but for some reason it no longer works as every request is saying

> You are requesting with an invalid credential.

I have noticed that if I look in the debugger that the `Authorization` request header does not show up. I have tested adding other headers in postman and those do show up.

I have the user model setup to find by access token in `common\models\User`:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }
```

And I have this in my behaviors function of the controller:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ];
        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'verbs' => ['GET'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Here is the components section of my main.php file:

```
'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'v1/login' => 'v1/login',
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/user']],
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/userinfo']],
                'v1/<controller>/<action>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add `CGIPassAuth on` to my directory configuration as Apache was hiding the authorization header.

Answer (score 2):

In your .htaccess file add :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Authorization Header with Basic format in your api.
Ex- Basic {token}

Comment: I do pass it on the request, is there something in the code I need to do to pass it?